# Sequelize synchronization on deploy

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've started using Sequelize for my projects and I don't know if I'm on the right way for the model relations init.

I've created an `init.js` used in 'postinstall` to synchronize my models :

```
const db = require('./models')

db.sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(
    (success) => {
      console.log("models synchronized");
    },
    (error) => console.log('Error: ', error)
  );
```

Is there a best way to synchronize models on deploy?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `postinstall` leaves your app dependent on `npm install` - what if you only make a DB scheme change which doesn't require any package updates?

Would be more reliable to either run as part of the app startup or as a separate script that could run on `start`